# how to lemmatize string containing numbers and special characters?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, lemmatization

I need to lemmatize strings containing numbers and alphanumeric characters. Example:

```
'strawberries1234!@ apples123@'
```

I also need to preserve those special characters and numbers. So the output for the above example would be,

```
'strawberry1234!@ apple123@'
```

I need to do this on a large dataset, so the code needs to be as efficient as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: More ellaboration needed. You just want to turn plural forms to singular forms? This isn't a small task as it seems to require some form of NLP. What have you tried so far?

Comment: basically, yeah. It's easy to extract the alphabets by just splitting using regex r'[^a-zA-Z]'. I don't know how to get back the numbers and the special characters though.

Comment: Regex has special characters to extract numbers.

Comment: those special characters and numbers should appear in the output in their respective positions after being processed. As I mentioned in the example,
'1234!@' in 'strawberries1234!@' should appear after 'strawberry' in the output... like 'strawberry1234!@'

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, this seems to be straightforward and needs no further elaboration of the task.
Use a regular expression in order to remove all sequences of special characters char-based, meaning that you do not simply sub() them but find the indexes. extract the remaining string using indexes, which would be the residual English words. lemmatize this (lemmatization is a process of removing suffixes in English, meaning that string elements at the right end of the string is being removed. (In other languages, you may in encouter infixes (xx-y-xx) and circumfigtion (y1-xx-y2), which may need more complex string operations). After that, simply concatenate the substrings with special characters again with the result of lemmatizing.

Comment: Interesting  noise in your data by the way, what is the background of this?